# unittest.skip not working if there is a setUp function

Tags: python-3.x, unit-testing, python-unittest

In the following code

```
class TestSomething(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        print("setting up")

    @unittest.skip("skip reason")
    def test_1(self):
        print("in test 1")

    def test_2(self):
        print("in test 2")
```

I expect only `test_2` to run. But both the tests are running. I suspect that this is due to the `setUp` function, because if I remove it then only `test_2` runs, as expected.

Is there a fix for this?

Answer (score 1):

`@unittest.skip(reason)` works fine with `setUp` method, can't reproduce it.

E.g.
`test_something.py`:

```py
import unittest


class TestSomething(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        print("setting up")

    @unittest.skip("skip reason")
    def test_1(self):
        print("in test 1")

    def test_2(self):
        print("in test 2")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

unit test results:

```sh
ssetting up
in test 2
.
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 2 tests in 0.000s

OK (skipped=1)
```